# Can I make RecursiveDirectoryIterator skip unreadable directories?

Tags: php, directory, directory-walk

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".")) as $file) {
  echo "$file\n";
}
```

Is there any way for this code to not throw UnexpectedValueException "failed to open dir: Permission denied" whenever there is a unreadable subdirectory inside directory I attempt to list?

**UPDATE**

Converting `foreach()` to `while()` and explicitly calling `Iterator::next()` wrapped in `try() catch {}`  doesn't help. This code:

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("."));
while($iter->valid()) {
    $file = $iter->current();
    echo "$file\n";
    try {
        $iter->next();
    } catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    }
};
```

is an infinite loop if there is unreadable subdirectory.

Comment: wrap it into try catch blocks. and it seems to be a bad ideea to create new objects right inside foreach parentheses

Comment: To Elaborate on s3v3n's comment. It seems to be a bad idea, because what exactly is going on is very hard to determine. Good code isn't always the smallest or fastest code.

Comment: It's not hard to determine what happens if you know what is RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator and what is their common use case.

It's simple code.

Comment: @s3v3n You gave me an idea of transforming foreach into while and explicitely calling iterator next() inside try {} catch. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently you can pass `$flags` parameter to constructor. There's only [one flag in the docs](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classRecursiveIteratorIterator.html#e831f5147ec06773875b31544c95d66c), but it does exactly what you want: `catches exceptions during getChildren() calls and simply jumps to the next element`.

Change your class creation code to

```
new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("."), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
```

and it should work

Comment: I have a similar problem asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410899/unable-to-skip-unreadable-directories-with-recursivedirectoryiterator do you have any ideas on how I can rework you solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Specifically, the flag is: CATCH_GET_CHILD

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this :

```
class ReadableFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator{
    public function accept(){
            return $this->current()->isReadable();
    }
}

$filteredIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new ReadableFilter(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".")));

foreach ($filteredIterator as $file){
    echo "$file\n";
}
```